# Не увеличивается счетчик значений при сравнении времени

Tags: java

Есть файл file.txt, в нем находятся n количество строк вида HH:ММ HH:ММ, где (00:00 ≤ HH:ММ ≤ 23:59). Необходимо узнать, находится ли первое значение строки(времени) в предыдущем промежутке, если да, то необходимо увеличить значение переменной int, т.е. есть строки "10:15 11:15" и "10:30 11:40". т.к "10:30" находится в промежутке "10:15 11:15", то счетчик увеличиваем.

```
public class TimeRecording {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    String line;
    int count = 0;

    // читаем фаил
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));

    List<Date> startList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Date> endList = new ArrayList<>();
    //пока есть строки, добавляем в List
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        Date startTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(line.substring(0, 5));
        Date endTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(line.substring(6, line.length()));

        startList.add(startTime);
        endList.add(endTime);
    }

    //Проходим циклом по List, если время находится в промежутке, делаем count++
    for (int i = 0; i < startList.size(); i++) {
        Date firstTime = endList.get(1);

        if (firstTime.after(startList.get(i)) && firstTime.before(startList.get(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Возможно я совсем не туда зашел, прошу помощи и благодарю за подсказки.

Comment: Почему `Date firstTime = endList.get(1)` всегда get 1?

Comment: Хм, приходит что-то типа "Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 MSK 1970". Проблема в этом?

"get 1", мне же надо сравнить с чем то вначале, явно здесь проблема, а как исправить не доходит.

Comment: вы распечатайте, например, первые 20 дат, и добавьте вопрос. Даты посомтрю и напишу алгоритм сравнения тогда

Comment: Вот такое печатает?

    `[Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 MSK 1970, Thu Jan 01 09:20:00 MSK 1970, Thu Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1970, Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 MSK 1970, Thu Jan 01 10:20:00 MSK 1970, Thu Jan 01 10:30:00 MSK 1970]`

Comment: Да вроде все ок с датами. Чуть позже напишу алгоритм

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
    for (int i = 0; i < startList.size()-1; i++) {
                Date comparedDate = startList.get(i + 1);  // Сравниваемая дата

// Сравниваем ее с датами из предыдущей строки
      if (comparedDate.after(startList.get(i)) &&  comparedDate.before(endList.get(i))) {
                    count++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вылетает
_Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
 at TimeRecording.main(TimeRecording.java:40)_

Comment: Поправьте условие `i < startList.size()-1`. Можно было и догадаться.